# At the opposite spectrum of "at best"

Tags: antonyms

The following was a comment of mine on an answer on Stack Overflow:

> This answer is misleading and incomplete at best. Plain wrong at worst.

My intent was to express that an indulgent interpretation will render it misleading and incomplete. A less forgiving one can go as far as saying it is just wrong.

I don't feel good about `at worst`. Is it a correct way to express this? I suspect it is, but even if it is I have the feeling it doesn't sound natural to an English speaking native.

Comment: Sounds perfectly natural to me, native AmE.

Comment: This sentence is misleading, and incomplete at best. As opposed to *this* sentence, which is misleading ***if not*** plain wrong.

Comment: I think the spectrum isn't too big here. "At least it's not going to be destructive if believed", is what I was going to say, but you already included *misleading* in a best case scenario, so simply being *wrong* isn't that horrible. (Hint: if the at worst scenario isn't that bad, using *at worst* isn't the ... um... worst thing you can say.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perfectly comprehensible but seems rather brusque to me (BrEng).

"*case a* at best, *case b* at worst" is normal usage. Where *case a* is bad and *case b* is even worse, it's a pretty dismissive thing to say.

It gives you you opportunity to criticise and then double-up on that criticism. Since your *case a* consists of two things ('incomplete' as well as 'misleading'), you've been able to go for triple-criticism. [Harsh](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=harsh).

> *Odo regarded Cisco as, as best, a necessary evil. At worst, a nuisance.*

[Star Trek: Deep Space Nine: The Siege](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_TrzBQUTcaQC&lpg=PA71&ots=XD95szybpy&dq=%22at%20best%22%20%22at%20worst%22%20odo&pg=PA71#v=onepage&q=%22at%20best%22%20%22at%20worst%22&f=false), Peter David

Comment: It is a perfectly well known idiomatic formulation. Whether it is 'brusque' or not, seems to me to depend on the context in which it is used.

Comment: @WS2, I agree, it's well-known ('normal usage' as I said). It's not necessarily brusque but [in the context of the OP's remark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174125/will-stdvectors-inside-another-vector-reallocate-when-the-first-vector-realloc/28174439#28174439) it sounds a lot like "shut up, stupid idiot" to me (BrEng). Clearly that's a matter of opinion though.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be harsh. I was just trying to point that the answer can be considered wrong.

Comment: +1 A E, @bolov - forgive the analogy, but it's like a 'double-jump & king-me' move in checkers, hard to resist but not wrong. Perhaps what troubles you is that your actual *intent* was to *edify* rather than to criticize.

Comment: Hi @bolov - yes, I thought that you probably weren't meaning to be harsh, that's actually why I mentioned the issue of tone - no-one wants to be *accidentally* harsh! ;)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be

> This answer is misleading and incomplete at best. *It may even be* plain wrong.

The subjunctive softens it.

Comment: Great suggestion. I removed my comment and replaced it with this.